# Import Analytics goals and Ecommerce transactions directly into AdWords account

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, google-ads, magento

I have a Magento-ecommerce site. Recently I migrated to Universal Analytics from Google Analytics. In Uiversal Analytics, I have tracked transaction data. It's tracking fine.

I have linked Analytics and **AdWords** account. In **AdWords**, accounts are integrated fine. But it did not integrate transaction data from Google Analytics.

After referred this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en), I did the importing of transaction data goals after checking all other settings. Even after 24 hours and more, in tracking status of Google AdWords, it shows **no recent conversions**. Till now it did not track transaction data.

As I'm referring **Google AdWords** for the first time, I could not find what wrong with this?

And one more thing I got from the [same](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en) link, We need to Import transaction data and goals once in 30 days manually. Can it be made to automatically import transaction data by any settings or any other? Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: And within this 24 hours, you're definitely sure the website has had a conversion via paid search (AdWords)?